# Making postfix clone emails to service

Tags: linux, email, postfix, service

I've created an SMTP service application that archives emails by some criteria. Now I need to make postfix send a copy to my service when it receives some mail.

Most obvious way to go would be to use "content_filter = my_service". Problem is, using content_filter I will need to re-send the mail back to postfix from my service, and I don't want to do that.
Is there a way to make postfix clone, not redirect, the messages to my SMTP service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `always_bcc`, `recipient_bcc_maps` and `sender_bcc_maps`, either in man 5 postconf or in the [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html). Easiest way is probably to send a copy to an address within `mydestination`, and using an entry in `/etc/aliases` (or wherever your `alias_maps` points to), forward those to a script which feeds them into your archiving application.

Edit: If you need an SMTP stream, set `always_bcc` to something like "archive@archive.local". Then add a custom transport table in `main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

and edit `/etc/postfix/transport` to include a line like:

```
archive.local smtp:[127.0.0.1]:5555
```

After executing postmap /etc/postfix/transport, you should get the raw SMTP data stream on port 5555 on you loopback interface.

Comment: Well, I am using the separate service application because performance is what I need here the most. And postfix documentation states that forwarding to scripts makes system work 4 times slower because it has to convert everything to non-native syntax. That's why I want to make it send the SMTP stream directly to my service application.

Comment: And yes, I forgot to mention, there seems to be no way to forward the mail with any of those commands to the service directly.

Comment: Have all mails bcc'd to, e.g., archive@archive.local. Create a transport_maps entry like "archive.local smtp:[127.0.0.1]:5555". Don't forget to read the documentation about transport tables.